# Calling a method every Day, every Week , every month and every year

Tags: java, timer, task, alarm

I need to autoSend reports to my clients at perticular timings like

- every day at 00:01 AM
- every Week at Sunday 00:01 AM
- on day 1 of every month
- on day 1 of every year

For every day i am doing this :

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

        System.out.println("context initiallized");
        System.out.println("Starting timer");

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Date alarmTime = calendar.getTime();

        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.schedule(new AlarmTask(), alarmTime);
    }
```

Here is the class where i perform my everyday task :

```
public class AlarmTask extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {
        // Do your work here; it's 00:01 AM!         
    }
}
```

It seems to work fine  **BUT**  when i start tomcat at anytime after 00:01 AM  Say at 02:30 AM the task is performed as soon as the context is loaded where i need it to be performed on next day...

Is their any problem with my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Calendar` models the full date so you have scheduled in the past. `Timer` will respond to that by executing immediately. Increment the day on the `Calendar`.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use QuartzSchedular http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) ? It could help you schedule your tasks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess u will have to do what Marko Topolnik said above https://stackoverflow.com/a/14781326/2040095

but in addition do u also need to invoke the 3 parameters form of method "schedule" for Timer class since you need this report to be send every day and not just one day ?

So something like

```
_timer.schedule(new AlarmTask(), alarmTime, period );
```

where **period** would be a 24 hours for daily reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in a huge projects I prefer you to go to [Quartz Schedular](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) since It has a user interface to handle jobs and create and edit jobs.  If it is just a small alarm task that has to executed periodically crate a batch file and add that to [chron](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) job to run in specific intervals.

Hope this will help..