# Once a week running timer

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks

I would like to get `java.util.Timer` instance which runs once a week. For example; it should run every Tuesday.
This code doesn't meet what I require.

```
java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
date1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.TUESDAY);
date1.set(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
date1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
date1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
timer.schedule(new MyTimer(), date1.getTime(), TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(7));
```

I searched for it in all questions, but there is no answer for that.
Is it impossible to do it with java.util.Timer?

Thanks in advance,
Best regards.

Comment: Why yOu did not consider this one [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781296/calling-a-method-every-day-every-week-every-month-and-every-year?rq=1]1

Comment: I've already checked it. Can you see something about weekly timer there?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Quartz:

http://quartz-scheduler.org/

It has better and less verbose ways of achieving what you want.

Look at this example:

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/examples/Example3

If you, for some reason, don't like Quartz, you can use the builtin ScheduledExecutorService:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: I dont want to use Quartz. Is it impossible to do it with java.util.Timer ?

Comment: It is very much possible even with Timer.

Comment: Could you give me an example by using Timer?

Comment: Why the heck do you want a Timer specifically? Use a scheduler, like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html. Is it a homework task or what?

Answer (score 0):

```
 java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
 Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
 date1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.TUESDAY);
 date1.set(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
 date1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
 date1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
 timer.schedule(new MyTimer(), date1.getTime(), TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(7));
```

Here actually you are trying to schedule a TIMER object on a interval of this  `TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(7)` specified time.

If you want to schedule the job on particular day. Create another scheduler which schedules your scheduler

```
   timer.schedule(timerObj,desiredDate)
```